# Having trouble importing sql file to heroku database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm running my application on mysql2 locally but I'd like to host it somewhere, so I tried heroku.
So I type this

heroku pg:psql -a app_name < sqlfile.sql

All I end up seeing is this

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO `view_jobchecklists` (`id`, `jobchecklist_id`, `...
```

And the line is

```
INSERT INTO `view_jobchecklists` (`id`, `jobchecklist_id`, `view`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `notes`, `time_of_day_shot`, `field_of_view`) VALUES
```

and it goes on for 100,000 lines, I'm not even sure this error is pointing out to the real problem, I'm trying to get all these tables into the postgres heroku database, it works just fine locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have a mysql exported file and trying to import into postgres.
If your file contains only INSERT statements then it could be done by replacing all ticks with `"`

Comment: There's about 100k lines it's not just insert statements
around 8,143 backticks, should every backtick be replaced?

Comment: Try it on one line first. But yes, all of them if 1 works

Comment: One unrelated question, how do I replace all the backticks, sublime text freezes?

Comment: Not sure how to answer that. Sublime is one of the fastest editors out there. Maybe your computer is too slow?